# So im trying to making custom routes for each document page using react-router-dom but i am getting Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to use the routes in `react-router-dom` but its not working and causes the following error:

> Server Error
> Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window."

```
import { NavigationSidebar } from "@/components/navigation/navigation-sidebar";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { currentProfile } from "@/lib/current-profile";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { HomeMobileToggle } from "@/components/home-mobile-toggle";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextEditors from "@/components/editor/TextEditorr";
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

const TextEditor = async () => {
    try {
        const server = await db.server.findFirst({});
        const currprofile = await currentProfile();
        
        if (!currprofile) {
            return <Navigate to="/" />;
        }

        const servers = await db.server.findMany({});

        return (
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Navigate to={`editor/${uuidV4()}`} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="editor/:id">
                        <div className="h-full">
                            <div className="hidden md:flex h-full w-[155px] z-30 flex-col fixed inset-y-0">
                                <NavigationSidebar />
                            </div>
                            <main className="md:pl-[180px] pr-[20px] h-full">
                                <HomeMobileToggle />
                                <div className="flex items-center justify-between mt-5">
                                    <div className="text-4xl ml-9">
                                        <strong>TEXT EDITOR</strong>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <Separator className="h-[3px] dark:bg-[rgb(92,41,96)] bg-[rgb(56,37,91)] w-full mt-4 mb-6" />
                                <TextEditors />
                            </main>
                        </div>
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in TextEditor component:", error);
        // You may want to handle errors more gracefully here
        return <div>Sorry, something went wrong.</div>;
    }
}

export default TextEditor;
```

Above is the code and i was expecting different urls

i am referring to [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRaelG7v0OU)

why is this happening??

Comment: Assuming you are using some Server-side Rendering library that allows for asynchronous component functions (*looks like you may be using Next.js*) an issue I see if that you are rendering a non-`Route` child to a `Route`. I don't know if this would throw the error you see though, directly or indirectly. Please [edit] to include the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace so we have better context. If you are using Next.js/SSR why are you using React-Router-DOM and client-side routing?